# Using literal numbers seems to break RegexIterator

Tags: php, regex, iterator

I have a piece of PHP code that stops working when I specify numbers as part of the regex. I am sure they do not need to be escaped but something is definitely wrong.

The code is as follows

```
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($IMAGES_DIR);
$iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
$rx = new RegexIterator($iter, $IMG_MASK, RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

$images = array();
foreach ($rx as $r) {
    $images[] = $r[0];
}
var_dump($images);
```

In the same directory as the PHP file is a directory named images, laid out like so:

```
images/
    1.png
    2.png
    3.png
    test/
        4.png
        5.png
        6.png
```

In the code, the constant `$IMAGES_DIR = 'images/'`.

When `$IMG_MASK = /^.+\.png$/` everything works fine - the dump contains all 6 images.

When `$IMG_MASK = /^[1-3]\.png$/` or `/^1\.png$/` or `/^\1\.png$/` (I didn't expect the last one to work, but gave it a shot) the dump is an empty array.

The regex seems to match fine in all the testers I put it against though. What am I missing?

Comment: What values do you ultimately want in the `$images` array? Should those be the filenames `1.png, 6.png`, or the paths `./images/1.png, ./images/test/6.png`?

Comment: The correct answer is up, so I suppose it doesn't matter, but I would like `$images` to contain full relative paths. I wanted to thank you for your comment - it wasn't the answer, but I feel like even if Michael hadn't posted it, I might well have figured it out in answering you.

Comment: You're welcome - it was both my comment and my answer. I had to assume you wanted the relative paths...

Comment: so it was - way to look at who you're speaking to, me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What looks to be happening here is that the directory itself in `$IMAGES_DIR` is included in the pattern returned to `$r` in your iteration.  Using your working pattern, if you `print_r($r);` inside the loop you'll see the matched patterns:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "./images/test/4.png"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "./images/test/6.png"
  [2]=>
  string(19) "./images/test/5.png"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "./images/3.png"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "./images/1.png"
  [5]=>
  string(14) "./images/2.png"
}
```

So, you need to construct your expression to either incorporate the directory, or to ignore it and not anchor with `^`. Your pattern as attempted matches *exactly* patterns like `1.png` but the input string it is testing is actuall `./images/1.png`.

Instead I would recommend using

```
$IMG_MASK = '#/[1-3]\.png$#';
```

This pattern does not `^` anchor the start of the string, and instead begins matching at the `/` before the digit.

If you are interested in getting the full paths, restore your `.+` to the start, and use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` just before the digit:

```
$IMG_MASK = '#.+' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '[1-3]\.png$#';
```

This will match anything (`.+`) up to a `/` (or your platform's separator), *then* match the single digit and `.png`. The result is an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./images/3.png
    [1] => ./images/1.png
    [2] => ./images/2.png
)
```

Of course if you want those images in `./images/test/` adjust the regex to use `\d\.png` to match any digit instead of just `[1-3]`.

The pattern

```
$IMG_MASK = '#.+' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '\d\.png$#';
```

...produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ./images/test/4.png
    [1] => ./images/test/6.png
    [2] => ./images/test/5.png
    [3] => ./images/3.png
    [4] => ./images/1.png
    [5] => ./images/2.png
)
```

Comment: This is exactly the issue, thankyou! The worst part is I momentarily considered leading directories and discarded it as the cause seeing as though the 'match-everything' regex still matched the images in the `test/` subdir. Of course they were matched though - dot matches directory separators. Thanks again!